# How to check if a property of a Firestore document exist in the security rules?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I thought `resource.data.someProperty != null` will be `true` when `someProperty` does not exist in the `resource` document but it seems not.

I tried `resource.data.someProperty != undefined` but it throws `Null value error` when testing with the simulator.

How exactly do I do that, and where is it documented? I am having trouble learning the security rules through reading the official references & guides.

Comment: Use the `in` operator of the map that contains the document.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think of document as a Map type.